# How to time travel with a game GTA IV EFLC mod

Tags: mods, grand-theft-auto-iv

How do I time travel in the GTA IV EFLC mod that I have downloaded from [moddb.com](http://www.moddb.com/mods/back-to-liberty-city/downloads/back-to-the-future-liberty-city). I don't know the assigned keys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there not documentation for the mod?  I'd suspect that would be the best place to check.

Comment: Have you tried accelerating to 88 mph?

Comment: I can't "turn time circuits on"

Comment: seems to me that there is no documentation, is it on moddb?

Answer (score 1):

From the README.txt file:

> To use the Timecircuits, you need to enable it with numpad +

And

> How to set the date with the numpad:
>
> - 4 Digits: HHMM
> - 8 Digits: MMDDYYYY
> - 12 Digits: MMDDYYYYHHMM
>
> And then press Enter

Please note that all of this features require a numeric keypad and will not work with the numbers under the F1-F12 row.